# c++ WriteFile unicode characters

Tags: c++, c++11, unicode

I'm trying to write a wstring into a UTF-8 file using WriteFile function.
I want the file to have these characters "ÑÁ" but I'm getting this "�".

Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winbase.h>
using namespace std;

const char filepath [] = "unicode.txt";

int main ()
{ 
   wstring str;
   str.append(L"ÑÁ");
   wchar_t* wfilepath;

   // Create a file to work with Unicode and UTF-8
   ofstream fs;
   fs.open(filepath, ios::out|ios::binary);
   unsigned char smarker[3];
   smarker[0] = 0xEF;
   smarker[1] = 0xBB;
   smarker[2] = 0xBF;
   fs << smarker;
   fs.close();

   //Open and write in the file with windows functions
   mbstowcs(wfilepath, filepath, strlen(filepath));
   HANDLE hfile;
   hfile = CreateFileW(TEXT(wfilepath), GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL,
       OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
   wstringbuf strBuf (str, ios_base::out|ios::app);
   DWORD bytesWritten;
   DWORD dwBytesToWrite = (DWORD) strBuf.in_avail();
   WriteFile(hfile, &strBuf, dwBytesToWrite, &bytesWritten, NULL);
   CloseHandle(hfile);
}
```

I compile it on cygwin using this command line:
`g++ -std=c++11 -g Windows.C -o Windows`

Comment: BTW, you don't need to use Hungarian notation because Microsoft does.  The compiler doesn't care about the spelling of identifiers; only that the names conform to the C++ language rules.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: not even MS uses (anti-) Hungarian Notation anymore. Their .NET naming guidelines says **DO NOT use Hungarian notation.**

Comment: Read http://utf8everywhere.org to see how to convert stuff to UTF-8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to convert the UTF-16 data to UTF-8 before writing it to the file.

And there is no need to create the file with `std::ofstream`, close it, and re-open it with `CreateFileW()`.  Just open the file once and write everything you need.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
//#include <codecvt>
//#include <locale>

#include <windows.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

LPCWSTR filepath = L"unicode.txt";

string to_utf8(const wstring &s)
{
    /*
    wstring_convert<codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> utf16conv;
    return utf16conv.to_bytes(s);
    */

    string utf8;
    int len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, s.c_str(), s.length(), NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (len > 0)
    {
        utf8.resize(len);
        WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, s.c_str(), s.length(), &utf8[0], len, NULL, NULL);
    }
    return utf8;
}

int main ()
{ 
    wstring str = L"ÑÁ";

    // Create a UTF-8 file and write in it using Windows functions
    HANDLE hfile = CreateFileW(filepath, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL,
       CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (hfile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        unsigned char smarker[3];
        DWORD bytesWritten;

        smarker[0] = 0xEF;
        smarker[1] = 0xBB;
        smarker[2] = 0xBF;
        WriteFile(hfile, smarker, 3, &bytesWritten, NULL);

        string strBuf = to_utf8(str);
        WriteFile(hfile, strBuf.c_str(), strBuf.size(), &bytesWritten, NULL);

        CloseHandle(hfile);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Btw, &utf8[0] is it a legit way to give the address of the chars array in the memory for winapi methods?

Comment: @user2134488 yes, it is perfectly legit, at least in C++11 and later which guarantee that the memory is contiguous, but in practice it was ok to do in earlier versions too

Answer (score 1):

Problem is here:

```
wstringbuf strBuf (str, ios_base::out|ios::app);
WriteFile(hfile, &strBuf, dwBytesToWrite, &bytesWritten, NULL);
```

`&strBuf` is the address of the `wstringbuf` object, which contains things like a pointer to the content, buffer position, and status flags... not where its contents are located.

You probably wanted

```
WriteFile(hfile, &str[0], /* etc */
```

but that will just store the same encoding that your `wstring` uses.  To write in UTF-8, you may want to use [`WideCharToMultiByte`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (or `wcstombs`, since you already used `mbstowcs`).

Comment: Hi, I tried this
`char* strBuf;`
`wcstombs(strBuf, str.c_str(), wcslen(str.c_str()));`
`WriteFile(hfile, &strBuf[0],...)`

But the out file is blank
What am I doing wrong

Comment: `wcstombs` doesn't allocate memory, you need to give it a pointer to a big enough buffer.

Comment: Important lesson, however I don't understand why Windows wants you to change from wchar to multibyte...

Comment: @NorbertBoros: Because UTF-8 is a variable length encoding?

Answer (score 0):

Ben is correct that you're writing raw `wchar_t` to the file, not UTF-8.

To write UTF-8, you might consider staying inside of C++ and doing this:

```
std::locale loc (std::locale(), new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>);

std::wofstream fs ("unicode.txt");
fs.imbue(loc);

fs << L"ÑÁ";
```

Comment: He's on `Windows`.. The above will require GCC-5.0 alpha/beta build or MSVC.

Comment: Actually I had tried what are you proposing, but didn't work
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28552985/includecodecvt-file-not-found?noredirect=1#comment45540405_28552985