# Char to unicode for WriteFile

Tags: c++, winapi, unicode, utf-8, wininet

I am downloading data using `InternetReadFile` which can store only to ansi buffer, i.e. to `char *`.

I need to parse data, obtained from `InternetReadFile`, which, can have Russian language symbols, and put it to csv file.

I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28622400/12450770), but it didn’t help. Before it, when I tried to write just `wchar_t` I got artifacts in notepad, while opening a csv file, and in another sheets apps. Using code from answer, notepad displays it correctly, but apps still not.

What am I doing now:

```
  char *name; // some ansi data from InternetReadFile, which is perfectly displayed by MessageBoxA
  wchar_t *nameW[100];
  AnsiToUnicode(name, nameW);
  int len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, *nameW, wcslen(*nameW), NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
  if (len>0)
        WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, *nameW, wcslen(*nameW), &name[0], len, NULL, NULL);

  HANDLE f = CreateFile(L"data.csv", GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
  DWORD wr;
  WriteFile(f, name, strlen(name), &wr, 0);
  CloseHandle(f);
```

[AnsiToUnicode from Microsoft.com](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/138813/how-to-convert-from-ansi-to-unicode-unicode-to-ansi-for-ole):

```
HRESULT __fastcall AnsiToUnicode(LPCSTR pszA, LPOLESTR* ppszW)
{

    ULONG cCharacters;
    DWORD dwError;

    // If input is null then just return the same.
    if (NULL == pszA)
    {
        *ppszW = NULL;
        return NOERROR;
    }

    // Determine number of wide characters to be allocated for the
    // Unicode string.
    cCharacters =  strlen(pszA)+1;

    // Use of the OLE allocator is required if the resultant Unicode
    // string will be passed to another COM component and if that
    // component will free it. Otherwise you can use your own allocator.
    *ppszW = (LPOLESTR) CoTaskMemAlloc(cCharacters*2);
    if (NULL == *ppszW)
        return E_OUTOFMEMORY;

    // Covert to Unicode.
    if (0 == MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, pszA, cCharacters,
              *ppszW, cCharacters))
    {
        dwError = GetLastError();
        CoTaskMemFree(*ppszW);
        *ppszW = NULL;
        return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(dwError);
    }

    return NOERROR;
}
```

How to correctly save unicode in that case?

Comment: You say the string has Russian characters in it. You store that into a char array. Then you convert that to wide char by assuming that the buffer is in the ascii code page [see the call to `MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP`]. This cannot be correct - the ascii code page doesn't have support for Russian characters. So you need to understand what code page the bytes you are reading is in. It could be one of the code pages which supports Russian characters or it could already be in UTF8. This is not something you can guess you must know it in advance.

Comment: Note that InternetReadFile doesn't change the code page or do any translation - its entirely up to the originating server to what format (code page) the bytes in the file are in. Over a normal http session utf8 is the norm, but that's not guaranteed.

Comment: @MikeVine the only url I access is https://google.com, it is always in utf-8, as I understand?

Comment: In which case just write the UTF8 to a file. You don't need any conversion to and from wide chars. However, you _may_ want to add a BOM to the file if it doesn't have one to allow editors to understand its in UTF-8 before you write the data: `unsigned char marker[3] = {0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF};WriteFile(hFile, marker, 3, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);`

Comment: @MikeVine after a few rebuilds what do I have: adding just `u8` doesn’t solve the problem. Adding the BOM You mentioned set notepad encoding "utf-8 with specification" and do not display symbols `u8` correctly, but manually resave file with just “utf-8" solves it, and it displays correctly in another apps too.

Comment: @MikeVine now works again with just u8 prefix, and without BOM.

Comment: `InternetReadFile` reads **raw bytes**. It doesn't use an *"ANSI buffer"*, as you believe. It's literally bytes, that **you** have to interpret. More likely than not, you are receiving UTF-8 encoded data, although you can inspect the HTTP headers to find the character encoding the server claims to send. Either way, the first step in fixing your issue is understanding the APIs you are using.

Comment: @IInspectable and @MikeVine However, now without encoding `InternetReadFile` output and with `u8` prefix for manually-created variables all works. Thanks both you for help