# WriteFile(...) changes file encoding from UTF-16 LE to UTF-8

Tags: file, winapi, encoding, utf-16, byte-order-mark

I have UTF-16 LE file. If I write the text to .txt file, it becomes UTF-8.
Code:

```
hFile = CreateFile(TEXT("D:\\clown.txt"), GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,  FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    wsprintf(buffer, TEXT("ERROR CODE: %i"), GetLastError());
    MessageBox(NULL, buffer, TEXT("Error"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    return 0;
}
MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("hFile was created"), TEXT("Successfully"), MB_OK);
sBuff = GetWindowText(hEdit, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
if (!WriteFile(hFile, buffer, sBuff * 2, &i, NULL))
{
    wsprintf(buffer, TEXT("ERROR CODE: %i"), GetLastError());
    MessageBox(NULL, buffer, TEXT("Error"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR); 
    return 0;
}
wsprintf(buffer, TEXT("%i"), GetLastError());
MessageBox(NULL, buffer, TEXT("Successfully"), MB_OK);
CloseHandle(hFile);
return 0;
```

WriteFileEx have the same problem

Comment: WriteFile has no idea of what a character or an encoding is, it only writes bytes. You're not writing UTF8 nor UTF16, you're writing whatever you got into buffer, directly into the file, as a bunch of bytes. Check this for some info about what a BOM is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/using-byte-order-marks and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28618715/c-writefile-unicode-characters

Comment: How do you know that the file is UTF-8? There is no code shown that reads the file. Also, the use of the TEXT macro raises the possibility that you are accidentally compiling in ANSI rather than Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

[`WriteFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-writefile) (and [`WriteFileEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-writefileex)) accept raw binary data and pass it to the device identified by the `hFile` parameter. No attempt is made to transcode or even interpret the data. The device receives a byte-for-byte copy of the input buffer.

When calling `WriteFile` on a file handle and the file contents aren't what you expected, the issue is with the *input* to `WriteFile` rather than an issue with the API itself. The input comes from a call to `GetWindowText`, and the problem is here, in all likelihood.

`GetWindowText` is a preprocessor macro that expands to either `GetWindowTextW` or `GetWindowTextA` depending on whether the `UNICODE` preprocessor symbol is defined. Since the code isn't self-sufficient, I'm going to have to guess here:

- The code is compiled using a C compiler
- The code author ignores compiler warnings
- `UNICODE` is not defined

Since we don't know with certainty what the problem is, the following is an educated guess: To solve the issue, replace `GetWindowText` with `GetWindowTextW`.